While downloading abernix:minifier-js@1.3.19...: error: certificate has expired
while running meteor remove standard-minifier-js && meteor add abernix:standard-minifier-js or meteor add abernix:standard-minifier-js getting below error. Any help would be highly appreciable.
While downloading abernix:standard-minifier-js@1.3.19...:
    error: certificate has expired


Check out the official Meteor documentation if one of the cases of expired certificates applies to you:
https://docs.meteor.com/expired-certificate.html
